# Black duck dynamic reference issues

Tags: dynamic, reference, nopcommerce, scanning

Actually I am looking for the solution of Dynamic reference issues found in Black Duck scan for my application for some of the below components/dlls-

1. ind-studio-scada
2. nopSolutions/nopCommerce
3. QuickPick ONE

The above components are dynamically linking with my application. So is there any way to troubleshoot it.